# Func syntax for async call

Tags: c#, multithreading, xamarin, xamarin.forms, func

I try to create an AsyncCommand with a parameter.

I used this method but it's not working.

```
 public static AsyncCommand<T> Create(Func<System.Threading.Tasks.Task<T>> func)
    {

        return new AsyncCommand<T>(new Command<T>(async (x) =>  await func(x)));
    }
```

And when I call it with my viewmodel:

```
 public ICommand OnRemoveTagCommand = AsyncCommand<ResultElementRatingDto>.Create(RemoveTag);

 private async Task<ResultElementRatingDto> RemoveTag(ResultElementRatingDto ratingDto)
    {

        return null;
    }
```

The error is:

> cannot convert from 'method group' to 'Func'

What's wrong in my code?

Comment: `RemoveTag` takes a DTO, where does that come from?

Comment: Comes from a binding with command parameter of a listview datatemplate Command="{ Binding OnRemoveTagCommand}" CommandParameter="{ Binding . }"

Comment: You could define the command directly like   `OnRemoveTagCommand= new Command(async(obj) => {});`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the overloads of `Create` that are available, and depending on the [language version you're using](https://github.com/dotnet/csharplang/blob/master/proposals/csharp-7.3/improved-overload-candidates.md), the compiler sometimes cannot resolve a method group to an unambiguous overload when only considering return types. In that case, call the method with a lambda expression:

```
public ICommand OnRemoveTagCommand = AsyncCommand<ResultElementRatingDto>.Create(x => RemoveTag(x));
```